# How to use ng-bootstrap Typeahead component on a Reactive Form

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the `ng-bootstrap` Typeahead component on a Reactive Form with Angular 2 and, after looking the example code on [Typeahead's documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead) I'm unable to get it to work.

Currently, I have something like:

```
<input type="text" aria-describedby="cityValid" class="form-control" id="inputCity" [formControl]="userForm.controls.city" [ngbTypeahead]="search">
```

With a `search` function almost identical as the example code, but it fails with the following stack trace

```
error_handler.js:53 TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at NgbTypeahead._subscribeToUserInput (typeahead.js:158)
at NgbTypeahead.ngOnInit (typeahead.js:52)
at DebugAppView._View_UserFormComponent0.detectChangesInternal (UserFormComponent.ngfactory.js:1093)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:271)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:376)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:297)
at DebugAppView._View_ExecutionFormComponent3.detectChangesInternal (ExecutionFormComponent.ngfactory.js:551)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:271)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:376)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.js:289)
```

What am I doing wrong? It would be great to have a general guide about how to use ng-bootstrap component on Reactive Forms, since the example are based on template-based ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem was that I took the search function that appeared on the example and converted it to a normal function but without returning any value.

I had

```js
searchCity (text$: Observable<string>) {
  text$
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
    : cities.filter(v => new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(v)).splice(0, 10));
}
```

Adding a `return` statement before `text$` fixed things.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to chain up a server call to the text$ observable to get the results from a server. That would be a mixing the synchronous chain above with an asynchronous server call but that won't fly. Anyone know?

Comment: Have you glanced [Typeahead's documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead)? There is an [example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/typeahead/demos/http/plnkr.html) of a Typeahead component that retrieves data from wikipedia. I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I did eventually find that, thanks. In my case I added this to the chain before the map call: `.switchMap(term => Observable.fromPromise(this.myStore.getData()))`, where getData() returns a promise that resolves with an array of search result objects